# Bad profile color (desaturated)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an huge color difference between Ai and all my others apps.
Ai looks desaturated.[image: Image for compare] Here are Ai next to Ps.

To solve the problem i checked "proof color" in the "Display" menu and choose "RVB Monitor" as proof format.

But all the img files I export still have the same color problem as Ai.

I think it might be a color profile mistake...

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Recalibrate your monitor and reset the Adobe color management preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that your Color Settings are "Synchronized" in the Edit > Color Settings Dialog. It should say "Synchronized" at the top. If it says "Unsynched", then the Working RGB color space could differ slightly between say PS and IL.

[image]

To make sure all apps are synched, go to Bridge > Edit > Color Settings and choose North America General Purpose. This will ensure that the working RGB and working CMYK will be consistent across all apps.